# SQL find reference id which no longer exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these tables:

- `tblCustomer` (CustomerID)
- `tblCustomerInqry` (CustomerID, CustInqryID)
- `tblSpecificConsideration` (CustInqryID)

I have this script, which lets me check if customer`s inquiry still exists even the customer is deleted:

```
SELECT 
    p.CustomerID
FROM
    tblCustomerInqry p
LEFT JOIN 
    tblCustomer v ON v.CustomerID = p.CustomerID
WHERE
    v.CustomerID IS NULL
    AND p.CustomerID IS NOT NULL
```

I need, after running this query, remove non-existing customer inquiries from `tblCustomerInqry`. Customer inquiry also has a reference in table `tblSpecificConsideration` with `CustInqryID` which also needs to be removed.

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should really do this using foreign keys.  When you define a foreign key, you can define cascading constraints.  These specify what happens when a value is deleted -- and you can automatically delete the referring records.

You can do the deletion as:

```
delete from tblCustomerInqry
    where not exists (select 1
                      from tblCustomer c
                      where c.CustomerID = tblCustomerInqry.CustomerID
                     );

delete from tblSpecificConsideration
    where not exists (select 1
                      from tblCustomerInqry ci
                      where ci.CustInqryID = tblSpecificConsideration.CustInqryID
                     );
```

You need to do the deletes in this order, so you delete the inquiry before the specific consideration.

However, the best way is to let the database do the work by using cascading deletes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but im getting two errors Incorrect syntax near 'ci and Incorrect syntax near 'sc'.

Comment: @Fresher . . . Table aliases are weird in the SQL Server `DELETE` statement because there are two competing `FROM` clauses.  So, I just removed the alias.

Comment: following error now:
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_tblSpecificConsideration_tblCustomerInqry". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASE", table "tblSpecificConsideration", column 'CustInqryID'.
The statement has been terminated.

(0 row(s) affected)